# Parsing date with timezone

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to match the following date with logstash:

```
Thu Apr 07 13:09:40 BST 2016
```

Using the following:

```
date {
    match => ["report_time", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"]
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"report_time", 
:value=>"Thu Apr 07 13:08:03 BST 2016", 
:exception=>"Invalid format: \"Thu Apr 07 13:08:03 BST 2016\" 
is malformed at \"BST 2016\"", :config_parsers=>"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", 
:config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}
```

I think it's the `z` part that is causing the issue, can someone please explain how I can parse the timezone i.e `BST`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a know issue of JODA (which is used by Logstash) which is not able to parse timezone names, in your case it's BST. (Timezone Name)

Reference Link:- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-timezone

To overcome this problem you can replace Timezone Name by the timezone offset.
You can change BST into equivalent offset such as +0100.

To do so add the following into your logstash configuration file:

```
mutate  {
gsub => ["report_time", "BST", "+0100"]
       }
```

It will replace as following:

"message" => "Thu Apr 07 13:09:40 BST 2016",

"report_time"=> "Thu Apr 07 13:09:40 +0100 2016",